# How to convert string into date?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js

in my application I want to show the last login of the user. From my backend I get this string: "lastLogin":"2022-02-22T06:02:53.585764600Z". In my frontend, I display it with:

```
<label class="lastVisitLabel">Last visit {{$store.state.user.lastLogin}}</label>
```

How can I format this string to a date type so I can use methods like .getHours() usw...

Comment: This is a json string, convert it to a javascript object and parse it with date()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/parsing-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden {{date($store.state.user.lastLogin)}} when I try this, it says that date is not a function

Comment: @MohammedAlwedaei not really, is there possibility to cast it inside the brackets?

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Just pass string to new Date method
const customDate = new Date("2022-02-22T06:02:53.585764600Z");

// Test
console.log(customDate.getHours());
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer for my problem,

```
{{Date($store.state.user.lastLogin)}}
```

Just use this to cast the string inside the brackets

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is that you can pass the string date from the backend into a Date object. And only then you will be able to use Date methods.

or in your case

```
{{Date{$store.state.user.lastLogin}}
```

Please refer to the attached code as a reference.

```js
//Value from DB
const strDate = "2022-02-22T06:02:53.585764600Z";

//Parse the date
const parsedDate = new Date(strDate);

document.querySelector("#display-date").textContent = parsedDate.getHours();
```

```html
<h1 id="display-date"></h1>
```

MDN Date docs: [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

W3schools [Date Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)